# Create a CDN across 2 servers

Tags: cdn

I have a dedicated server in the US and a virtual server in the UK and I would like to be able to serve a site from either server depending on which one is closer to the user.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you should probably have an appreciation of [GeoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoip) and [GeoDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodns).

However if that's too much reading, take a look at this near identical question from the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/30567/geo-dns-providers) SE site, as the answers give some good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how busy your site is, I'd just pony up for CloudFront or another PAYG CDN